# How to use super.generate() in IdentifierGenerator hibernate 6.2.2?

Tags: hibernate

At Hibernate 5, I can use like that

```kotlin
class UseIdOrGenerate : IdentityGenerator() {
    override fun generate(session: SharedSessionContractImplementor, obj: Any?): Any {
        val id = session.getEntityPersister(null, obj).getIdentifier(obj, session) as Int
        return if (id == 0) super.generate(session, obj) else id
    }
}
```

but at hibernate 6, I can't use super.generate() because IdentifierGenerator is interface and generate() is a interface method. So if I write a code like below,

```kotlin
class UseIdOrGenerate : IdentifierGenerator {
    override fun generate(session: SharedSessionContractImplementor, obj: Any?): Any {
        val id = session.getEntityPersister(null, obj).getIdentifier(obj, session) as Int

        return if (id == 0) super.generate(session, obj) else id
    }
}
```

the compiler says that "Abstract member cannot be accessed directly". How to fix it so that I can use the default strategy?

Answer (score 1):

Here you have to `override` the `generate` method with custom logic what you already did based on method signature (`override fun generate(...)`. Now you just have to do some custom logic when id is 0

Something like next one approach as a example

```
//This is an example never do it in production. You must have custom one
Random random = new Random();   
// Generates random integers 0 to 49  
int x = random.nextInt(50);
```

And then instead of

`super.generate(session, obj)`
You have to return it

```
return if (id == 0) x else id
```

And compile error should disappear.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I want to use GenerationType.IDENTITY when id is 0.